# Proper way to pass optional parameter if not null Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to pass optional parameter into a function only if its not null in Javascript? Else, do not pass this parameter at all.

For example, the below function, how to not insert c parameter if var_c is null

```
function({
a:var_a,
b:var_b||'b', //if b is null, set is as string b
c:var_c||null //how to check if c is null and do not insert this parameter at all into function
})
```

Update:
I ended up using as below. It works for my use case, not sure if it is the best practice

```
function({
a:var_a,
b:var_b||'b', 
c:var_c|| undefined
})
```

Comment: Where are these parameters coming from? function params? can you expand your example to show more information?

Comment: These parameter could be either query param for http call; for certain get call, not all query params will be passed from the get call 
I understood we could pass in default args if null such as for var_b, but I was wondering if there's a way to not pass the argument in at all

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like below:

```
function f() {
  ...
}


function test(param1, param2, param3){
  const myArgs = [ param1, param2];
  if(param3) myArgs.push(param3);

  f(... myArgs);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

see below

```
function test(a, b, c){ 
    if (c == undefined){
        ....
    } else {
        ..
    }
....
}

if (c == null){
  test(a,b);
} else {
  test(a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is feasible and would be my go to, but im hoping to find a less boilerplate method if it exists. If i have multiple optional parameter, I would have to put alot of if/else switch statement

Comment: well I'm assuming different parameters would lead to different behaviours, so you kinda of have to use many if/else at somewhere in your code, and function itself would be a good place to be if you are gonna define those if/else anyway.